# SQL Server 2008 R2: Show only recently added records

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I have two tables:

1. Cust : Contains customer details like customer ID and customer Name.
2. Cust_Address : This table contains customer ID and customer address.

**Table**: `Cust`

```
create table cust
(
  cust_id int,
  cust_name varchar(10)
);
```

**Records Insertion**:

```
insert into cust values(1,'A');
insert into cust values(2,'B');
insert into cust values(3,'C');
insert into cust values(4,'D');
```

**Table**: `Cust_Address`

```
create table cust_address
(
  cust_id int,
  cust_add varchar(50)
);
```

**Records Insertion**:

```
insert into cust_address values(1,'US');
insert into cust_address values(2,'UK');
insert into cust_address values(3,'UAE');
insert into cust_address values(4,'SA');
insert into cust_address values(1,'AUS');
insert into cust_address values(2,'IND');
insert into cust_address values(3,'SL');
insert into cust_address values(1,'CHINA');
```

Now I want to show the result which contains the latest customer address which have been inserted in the table `Cust_Address`.

**Expected Result**:

```
Cust_ID    Cust_Name   Cust_Add
-------------------------------
1          A           CHINA
2          B           IND
3          C           SL
4          D           SA
```

Here is the [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b1dc0/2) for tables and its records.

Comment: You can add a column called created date and order by that column

Comment: @User2012384, You mean it's not possible without having date column?

Comment: Or you can order by the Cust_ID column, but there's no way to know which record is recently inserted

Comment: @MAK: no, if you want to know about when a row was inserted, it's up to **you** to have a `DateCreated` column which you can query later on. SQL Server as such doesn't provide that capability

Comment: you can enable change data capture in your database and on that particular table. the CDC table will hold last inserted records

Comment: Okay! Thank you everyone

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not able to retrieve the rows in any particular order. You need some more info to get an order.
The best way is **primary index** in Cust_address

```
CustAddrID int identity(1, 1) not null primary key
```

You can also have a **CreatedOn** column that will have default value equal to **getDate()**

After that you can figure out what is the last inserted value for **CustAddr** for each **Cust** record.

In case you are not able to add new column there then maybe 
[change tracking](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280358(v=sql.105).aspx) functionality. But your issue seems to be too trivial for that.

There are also [Temporal Tables](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3680/introduction-to-sql-server-2016-temporal-tables/) in SQL Server 2016. But again it's probably too much.

Here is an example how you can get the address using primary key **CustAddrID** 
[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/7da865/11/0)

```
select  cust_name, cust_add
from cust C 
join 
(select 
  cust_add, cust_id,
  row_number() over (partition by cust_id  order by cust_add_id desc) rn
  from cust_address ) CLA
 on CLA.cust_id = C.cust_id and
    CLA.rn = 1
```

Identity column increases every time when we insert new value to the table. The correct value for your case will be the record with the highest cust_add_id and specified cust_id.

In the above query we generates numbers in desc order starting from 1 using **row_number()** function for each **cust_id** (partition by cust_id). Finally we take only the records with generated number **rn**  equal to 1 **CLA.rn = 1** and we join it to **cust** table.

You can replace row_number() by max(cust_add_id) and group by cust_id. However in that case you need to join cust_add table twice.

Comment: Thank you. But after creating column CustAddrID, how to retrieve the expected result.

Comment: @MAK I added sample to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You will not be able to get the rows out of the link table in the order they were inserted.

You need to have a column for this.

Imagine how big the meta-data would be if you needed to keep a record for each record for creation! Would you also want to keep meta-data on your meta-data so you know when the meta-data was updated? The space use can quickly escalate.

SQL Server keeps some stats but something this specific will need to come from a user-defined field.

So you either use a identity column in the CustAddr table [CustAddr int identity(1, 1) not null primary key] or add a column for createdDateAndTime DateTime Default GetDate().